# Hide "Terminated/Killed" message after killing a group of processes

Tags: bash

So i am trying to hide the Killed message after executing the following command:
`while :;do echo 1;done 2>/dev/null|./scr.sh 2>/dev/null`

with the scr.sh containing:
`kill -9 -- -$(ps -o pgid= $$ | grep -o [0-9]*)`

But it doesn't work. The scr.sh is supposed to kill all the processes in the current pipe which i try to do by killing all the processes in its process group.

Comment: do you know which of the processes is giving the message? My guess is that it's the shell that it opens to run scr.sh. You can `grep -v` the shell process, so it will kill everything *else* and the shell will terminate gracefully, thus not showing the message.

Comment: try /dev/null for each command until you found the right one (start with kill)

Comment: tried that, couldn't get it to work